# StartActivity - ActionView cannot open document - Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, uri, storage, actionview

```
var storage_path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;

filePathh = Path.Combine(storage_path, filename); 

Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(filePathh); 
Console.WriteLine("Downloaded file PATH: " + Query.filePathh);

Intent open = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
open.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
open.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;

Android.Net.Uri fileUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, "com.companyname.Login.provider", file).NormalizeScheme();
Console.WriteLine("File uri: " + fileUri.Path);
open.SetDataAndType(fileUri, "*/*");

Intent intentC = Intent.CreateChooser(open, "Open With");
intentC.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);

intentC.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intentC);
```

When trying to open a file (when choosing an app to open it - like Docs or HTML reader) we get error File Not Found.

We saw that **filePathh** and **fileUri** are different and are not pointing to the same location.

For storage_path:
storage/emulated/0/Download/How_to_initialize_your_Xamarin_app_to_use_AppConnect_C#_APIs.pdf

For Uri path:
/external/Download/How_to_initialize_your_Xamarin_app_to_use_AppConnect_C#_APIs.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

I put a PDF in Download folder, I use following code to open it.

```
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {


            var storage_path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;

            var filePathh = Path.Combine(storage_path, "test.pdf");

            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(filePathh);

            Intent open = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);

            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, PackageName + ".provider", file);

            open.SetDataAndType(photoURI, "application/pdf");
            open.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
            Intent intent = Intent.CreateChooser(open, "Open File");

            try
            {
                StartActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

Please add `provider` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and read/write persmission.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.app17" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <provider
           android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
           android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
           android:exported="false"
           android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>

  </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Create a xml folder in Resource folder and add following `provider_paths.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Here is my demo's link.

https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/App17.zip

Please put PDF in the Download folder like following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: FileProvider and read/write permissions were already asked for and granted.
We have provider_paths.xml that has been set up to have all the file paths that can be.
The only difference is that we did not utilize xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
We are also having issues with Uri photoUri, since it must be Android.Net.Uri type of file, not System.Uri
After running code like yours, with changes made to photoUri type, we get an error
'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()'

Comment: I update my demo, please see my answer. you can download it and test it.

Comment: Okay, we saw your demo, thank you very much for it, BUT
You are calling this from MainActivity.cs where we are calling this through one of our pages like ListOfAttachments.xaml.cs which calls a class that does the StartActivity.
We did this because ListOfAttachments.xaml.cs inherits ContentPage and there is no definition of StartActivity method so we call a different class that inherited Activity...

Comment: If you use xamarin forms, You can use dependence service to call it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction , If you want to use Activity in depenedence service, you can use   Current Activity Plugin to get it 
 https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin.